# DateTime format in kendo DatePickerFor for international web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a web in MVC core. This web works for many countries and each country must see their own DateTime format.

Internally, web has System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture and System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture defined in "en".

I am using Kendo in Views and works fine when dates has correct format: "MM/dd/yyyy".

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.Date).Format($"{{0:g}}").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }))
```

When I am working for Australia date format is "dd/MM/yyyy". I can modify this format in the view:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.Date).Format($"{{0:{"dd/MM/yyyy"}}}").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }))
```

But, when I save information, view model property return null value and fail.

View model has following code:

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

View has following code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.Date).Format($"{{0:g}}").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }))
```